How to selectively truncate a file from a specific point to another in Python?
I am looking for a way to truncate a section of a file in Python, similar to how truncate() works, but instead of cutting off from the current position to the end of the file, I need to remove a specific section, say from byte 10 to byte 20.
The challenge is that these files can be quite large, and I want to avoid loading the entire file into memory due to memory constraints.

Note that truncating by definition means "removing everything after position X". What you want to do is more like file surgery, where you pipe data from your input file into a new output file until you reach X, keep reading the input file but not pipe data until you reach Y, then start piping data again. You're going to have to work with the file's data, but you won't have to load the entire file into memory all at once (e.g. you can use a buffered stream)

No I want to cut of the middle of the file not opposite. And my file is very large and I don't have too much time to read it.

I didn't say the opposite. As for details about why you need to do this: remember to put those in your post, not in comments. You may also want to consider "just not using python" and instead use command line utilities that can cut up and join files, and then simply have Python call those in the correct order using subprocess. Or not even use Python at all.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Then I misunderstood, My apologize

You mean can I do it with subprocess? Can you show me how?

no I mean that subprocess  in Python lets you run system calls like cat, head, and tail, where you use normal unix commands to get the first X bytes from a file, as well as the last Y bytes from a file, and then concatenate those as a new file.

you can use standard open(), read(), write() in bytes mode and read-write mode with seek() to move from one place to another place in file. And read(size) can read only part of file. But still it need to read some part, move to destination place, write data, move again to source place to read next part of file, etc. If you will bigger part of file then it may work faster. But maybe if you use programs created in C/C++/Rust/Go then they will work faster.
